# Vue, Vuex - Is it a good way to use store from filter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new in Vue and can't understand some simple things.
I have store based on Vuex. Each 15 seconds Im fetching USDEUR currency rate from API. 
In my component I have fixed price in dollars, and I have to replace it with Euro price.
Is it a good way to use filter for it? And how to implement it?

Store:

```
actions: {
   async fetchRate ({ commit }) {
     let rate = await Promise.all([getUSDEURRate()])
     commit('setUSDEURRate', rate)
   }
}
getters: {
   return getCurrencyRate(state)
}
```

Component (I use this part many times on the page)

```
<div>The price is {{ priceInUsd | toEuro }}</div>
```

main.js

```
Vue.filter('toEuro', value => {
  return value * HERE_NEED_TO_GET_EURO_RATE_FROM_STORE
})
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchRate')
    setInterval(() => {
     this.$store.dispatch('fetchRate')
    }, 15000)
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thank you for helping in code structure.

Comment: By the way, if your code *works* but you'd like to make it *better*, you might be better of on [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) rather that StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Big thanx. I will check it right now. But unfortunatelly my code isn't working yet. I dpon't know how to get store from global filters

Answer (score 1):

According to the VueJS docs:

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common
> **text formatting**.

(Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

This is not a formatting issue, so I wouldn't use **filters** in this case.

You could do it like this:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    rates: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    currentRate: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    setCurrentRate(state, next) {
      if (next) {
        state.currentRate += 1
      } else {
        state.currentRate = 0
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchRate(ctx) {
      if (ctx.state.currentRate < 9) {
        ctx.commit('setCurrentRate', 1)
      } else {
        ctx.commit('setCurrentRate', 0)
      }
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  store,
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    amountInUSD: 0,
    currentRate: 1 // only for displaying the rate
  },
  computed: {
    amountInEUR() {
      // the conversion calculation is here:
      return this.amountInUSD * this.$store.state.rates[this.$store.state.currentRate]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchRate')
      this.currentRate = this.$store.state.rates[this.$store.state.currentRate]
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="amountInUSD" type="number"> USD<br />
  <div>Current rate: {{currentRate}}</div><br />
  <div>Current value in EUR: {{amountInEUR}} EUR</div>
</div>
```

In the snippet I created a mock dataset and function, but the main point is, that the conversion calculation is done in a **computed** property.

You could also move the whole thing into the store, if more than one component use these values.